# Route undefined for my controller CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm on CodeIgniter and I have a problem.

I created a Controller called View.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class View extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('client'); 
    }

    public function index(){
        echo "Test";
        /*$client = $this->client->getClientByID($idClient);
        echo json_encode($client);*/
    }
}
```

But when I call him in the browser, he says : The requested URL /Modules/CommExpert/View/ was not found on this server.

index() in the Controller View is defined and just has an echo in it.

Can someone explains me ? Thanks :D

Comment: Are you using HMVC or something else that is not exact just a CI installation?

Comment: The thing is that in my project, I have to code a new module in an existing project.

And I have the feeling that CI doesn't find the controller. Bad route, bad htaccess ?

Comment: Can you double check if the name `View` is a CodeIgniter Reserved word or if this is your first Controller to view on any browser..can you also check if your htaccess allows you to view

Comment: Try URL with `/CommExpert/View`.

Comment: No changes, still have the same 404 error

Comment: Show your routes,php

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'accueil';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: Can you show your application folder inner folders organization?
Describe your folders tree, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part I.**
If you get stuck - perform a test by doing something a little different.

For instance - Create a new module called test
Under your new modules/test/controllers/ create a new controller called test.php or for CI 3 Test.php

So now you have /application/modules/test/controllers/Test.php ( for CI 3 )

In your test.php controller put

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        echo "This is the Test controller from my test module";
    }
}
```

And see if you can get that to work!

**Part II:**

I see that you have tried /CommExpert/View in your URL and got a 404.

Be careful of case. Windows and MAC's don't care about case sensitivity. Linux Systems do.

Did you try yourdomain.com/commexpert/view.
After a little experimenting I found that you can have a controller called view (personally, I'd try to go for something different). 
Also you can have either view or View in the URL and both work.

What is important is the case of the controller. 
In my testing where I have a module called admin, and I have created a controller called view, I get the following... **

> NOTE: This is for CI 3.0
>
> ```
>     URL                  Result
>
> domain.com/admin/view -> Works ( Lower case v in view )
> domain.com/admin/View -> Works ( Upper case V in View )
>
> domain.com/Admin/view -> 404 ( Big Admin, Lower case v in view )
> domain.com/Admin/View -> 404 ( Big Admin, Lower case V in view )
> ```

See if that helps you any!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my .htaccess :

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|editor|css|js|scripts|images|img|media|xml|user_guide|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```